# How do I reference a local DLL with Waf in Windows?

Tags: windows, waf, build-tools

Following the [example given in *The Waf Book*](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html#_library_interaction_use),
I have the setup described below, which builds a shared lib and a static lib, and then links them to an exe. My system is
running Windows 7 with VS2013 MSVC.

When I build with the sample `wscript`, the build fails with:

```
Build failed
-> missing file: 'D:\\src\\waf-example\\demo\\build\\lib1.lib'
```

I noticed that despite the `bld.shlib` usage (which adds a task to build a shared lib, named 'lib1', from `a.c`), the build output shows
*both* a DLL and a LIB entry, when I would only expect a DLL entry.

```
[5/8] cshlib: build\a.c.1.o -> build\lib1.dll build\lib1.lib build\lib1.dll.manifest
```

*The Waf Book* shows build output from a Linux system that does not have this problem:

```
[6/8] cshlib: build/a.c.0.o -> build/liblib1.so
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

#### wscript from The Waf Book

```
def options(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')

def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')

def build(bld):
        bld.shlib(
                source = 'a.c',
                target = 'lib1'
                )

        bld.stlib(
                source = 'b.c',
                use    = 'cshlib',
                target = 'lib2')

        bld.shlib(
                source = 'c.c',
                target = 'lib3',
                use    = 'lib1 lib2')

        bld.program(
                libpath='.',
                source = 'main.c',
                target = 'app',
                use    = 'lib3')
```

#### files

```
D:\src\waf-example\demo>tree /F /A
D:.
|   a.c
|   b.c
|   c.c
|   main.c
|   waf-1.7.15
\---wscript
```

#### output

```
D:\src\waf-example\demo>python waf-1.7.15 clean build --zones=runner
'clean' finished successfully (0.008s)
Waf: Entering directory `D:\src\waf-example\demo\build'
[1/8] c: a.c -> build\a.c.1.o
15:52:00 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '..\\a.c', '/FC', '/c', '/Foa.c.1.o']
[2/8] c: b.c -> build\b.c.2.o
15:52:00 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '..\\b.c', '/FC', '/c', '/Fob.c.2.o']
[3/8] c: c.c -> build\c.c.3.o
15:52:00 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '..\\c.c', '/FC', '/c', '/Foc.c.3.o']
[4/8] c: main.c -> build\main.c.4.o
15:52:00 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '..\\main.c', '/FC', '/c', '/Fomain.c.4.o']
a.c
[5/8] cshlib: build\a.c.1.o -> build\lib1.dll build\lib1.lib build\lib1.dll.manifest
15:52:00 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\LINK.exe', '/NOLOGO', '/MANIFEST', '/IMPLIB:lib1.lib', '/DLL', 'a.c.1.o', '/OUT:D:\\src\\waf-example\\demo\\build\\lib1.dll', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\lib\\winv6.3\\um\\x64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\Neutral', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\ExtensionSDKs\\Microsoft.VCLibs\\12.0\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\neutral']
b.c
[6/8] cstlib: build\b.c.2.o -> build\lib2.lib
15:52:00 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\LIB.exe', '/NOLOGO', '/OUT:lib2.lib', 'b.c.2.o']
c.c
main.c
15:52:00 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64\\MT.exe', '/NOLOGO', '-manifest', 'D:\\src\\waf-example\\demo\\build\\lib1.dll.manifest', '-outputresource:D:\\src\\waf-example\\demo\\build\\lib1.dll;2']
Waf: Leaving directory `D:\src\waf-example\demo\build'
Build failed
-> missing file: 'D:\\src\\waf-example\\demo\\build\\lib1.lib'
```

Comment: Can you post your `a`,`b`,`c` files too? I'd be happy to give it a run.

Comment: @drahnr, Thanks, much appreciated! I figured out the problem. I'll post the answer later tonight.

Comment: @superuser, the people demand an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that waf requires you to specify a [.def file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx) for shared libraries on windows. Using .def files is good practice, but shouldn't be mandatory so maybe it is a bug in Waf you've found.

I just changed the `lib1` and `lib3` targets to:

```
bld.shlib(source = 'a.c', target = 'lib1', defs = 'a.def')
bld.shlib(source = 'c.c', target = 'lib3', 
          use = 'lib1 lib2', defs = 'c.def')
```

The def files are just dummies like:

```
EXPORTS
    foo
```

And that seemed to be enough to get the build to run.